# Row_number and union

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query for an hackerrank challenge, now my query looks like this:

```
(SELECT q1.city,q1.charsize (
    SELECT 
        city
        , MIN(LENGTH(city)) as charsize
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY charsize,city order by city) as rowno
    from station
   ) q1 
WHERE q1.rowno = 1)
UNION
(SELECT q2.city,q2.charsize (
    SELECT 
        city
        , MAX(LENGTH(city)) as charsize
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY charsize,city order by city) as rowno
    from station
   ) q2 
WHERE q2.rowno = 1);
```

But when I execute it I get the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 
        city
        , MIN(LENGTH(city)) as charsize
        , ROW_NUMBE' at line 2
```

This means that I am doing something that is wrong syntax wise, I have little experience with sql in general and I had a look at the docs already but I am struggling to understand why.

If it can be of any use, this is the table structure:

[image: Table structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten a few `FROM` keywords. 
And you I think you should be using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

```
(SELECT q1.city,q1.charsize FROM (
    SELECT 
        city
        , MIN(LENGTH(city)) as charsize
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY charsize,city order by city) as rowno
    from station
   ) q1 
WHERE q1.rowno = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT q2.city,q2.charsize FROM (
    SELECT 
        city
        , MAX(LENGTH(city)) as charsize
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY charsize,city order by city) as rowno
    from station
   ) q2 
WHERE q2.rowno = 1);
```

This query should work assuming you use MySQL 8.0+

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still gives me other syntax errors: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY charsize,city order by city) as rowno
    from station
   ) q1 
WH' at line 5`

Comment: @F.Leone this query works on MySQL 8.0! Are you on MySQL 8.0 looking to the syntax error you arn't! Use `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Yes! This is correct, I was looking at the 8.0 docs hence the query came out that way. With a select version I got `5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 `. Thanks for the help! I will convert this in 5.7 . My bad, next time I will check in which environment I am